# how to convert row to column if unknown number of columns SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

I have data like this:

```
 MaGiangVienID  |  SoTiet1  |  SoTiet2  |  DateID
79000G07.000206 |      60   |    60.00  |     t11
79000G07.000206 |      54   |    54.00  |     t12
```

I want to my result like this:

```
 MaGiangVienID  | SoTiet1_t11 | SoTiet2_t11 | SoTiet1_t12 | SoTiet2_t12
79000G07.000206 |          60 |       60.00 |          54 |       54.00
```

I don't know how many columns because `MaGiangVienID` have a lot of `DateID`

Please help me!!Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

For this type of data transformation you need to apply both the [`UNPIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) functions. The `UNPIVOT` takes the data from the multiple columns and places it into rows and then the `PIVOT` takes the rows and converts it back to columns.

To perform the `UNPIVOT` all of the values that you convert to rows must be the same datatype so conversion might be needed.

**Unpivot**:

```
select MaGiangVienID, 
    value, 
    col +'_'+DateId col
from
(
  select MaGiangVienID, 
    cast(SoTiet1 as varchar(50)) SoTiet1, 
    cast(SoTiet2 as varchar(50)) SoTiet2,
    DateID
  from yourtable
) src
unpivot
(
  value
  for col in (SoTiet1, SoTiet2)
) unpiv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1b1cf/1). The result of the unpivot is:

```
|   MAGIANGVIENID | VALUE |         COL |
-----------------------------------------
| 79000G07.000206 |    60 | SoTiet1_t11 |
| 79000G07.000206 | 60.00 | SoTiet2_t11 |
| 79000G07.000206 |    54 | SoTiet1_t12 |
| 79000G07.000206 | 54.00 | SoTiet2_t12 |
```

As you see the `UNPIVOT` generates the new column names with the `DateId` appended to the end of it. Now you apply the `PIVOT` function.

**Static PIVOT:**

```
select MaGiangVienID, SoTiet1_t11, SoTiet2_t11, SoTiet1_t12, SoTiet2_t12
from
(
  select MaGiangVienID, 
    value, 
    col +'_'+DateId col
  from
  (
    select MaGiangVienID, 
      cast(SoTiet1 as varchar(50)) SoTiet1, 
      cast(SoTiet2 as varchar(50)) SoTiet2,
      DateID
    from yourtable
  ) src
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (SoTiet1, SoTiet2)
  ) unpiv
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in (SoTiet1_t11, SoTiet2_t11, SoTiet1_t12, SoTiet2_t12)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/98519/8)

Now the above version works great if you have a known number of `DateId` values but you stated that you don't so you will want to implement this same query using dynamic sql.

**Dynamic PIVOT:**

```
DECLARE @colsUnpivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsPivot as  NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsUnpivot = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
         from sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = object_id('yourtable') and
               C.name not in ('MaGiangVienID', 'DateID')
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' 
                      + quotename(c.name + '_'+t.DateId)
                    from yourtable t
                    cross apply sys.columns as C
                   where C.object_id = object_id('yourtable') and
                         C.name not in ('MaGiangVienID', 'DateID')

            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query 
  = 'select MaGiangVienID, '+@colsPivot+'
      from
      (
          select MaGiangVienID, value, col +''_''+DateId col
          from
          (
            select MaGiangVienID, 
              cast(SoTiet1 as varchar(50)) SoTiet1, 
              cast(SoTiet2 as varchar(50)) SoTiet2,
              DateID
            from yourtable
          ) src
          unpivot
          (
            value
            for col in ('+@colsUnpivot+')
          ) unpiv
      ) src
      pivot
      (
        max(value)
        for col in ('+ @colspivot +')
      ) p'

exec(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ec903/4)

Both versions produce the same result:

The result is:

```
|   MAGIANGVIENID | SOTIET1_T11 | SOTIET2_T11 | SOTIET1_T12 | SOTIET2_T12 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 79000G07.000206 |          60 |       60.00 |          54 |       54.00 |
```

If you do not have access to the `UNPIVOT`/`PIVOT` functions then you can replicate the query.  The `UNPIVOT` function can be replicated using a `UNION ALL` and the `PIVOT` can be produced using a `CASE` statement with an aggregate function:

```
select MaGiangVienID,
  max(case when col = 'SoTiet1_t11' then value end) SoTiet1_t11,
  max(case when col = 'SoTiet2_t11' then value end) SoTiet2_t11,
  max(case when col = 'SoTiet1_t12' then value end) SoTiet1_t12,
  max(case when col = 'SoTiet2_t12' then value end) SoTiet2_t12
from
(
  select MaGiangVienID, 'SoTiet1_t11' col, cast(SoTiet1 as varchar(50)) value
  from yourtable
  where DateID = 't11'
  union all
  select MaGiangVienID, 'SoTiet2_t11' col, cast(SoTiet2 as varchar(50)) value
  from yourtable
  where DateID = 't11'
  union all
  select MaGiangVienID, 'SoTiet1_t12' col, cast(SoTiet1 as varchar(50)) value
  from yourtable
  where DateID = 't12'
  union all
  select MaGiangVienID, 'SoTiet2_t12' col, cast(SoTiet2 as varchar(50)) value
  from yourtable
  where DateID = 't12'
) src
group by MaGiangVienID
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1b1cf/4)

All versions will produce identical results.

Comment: @Khanh I am not sure what you mean that you got the data from select command? Where are you running your current query?